# Symfony Form - Allow removal of nested form associated entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `/checkout` JSON API endpoint which allows an optional `billingAddress` parameter alongside other parameters such as email and `deliveryAddress`.

These addresses are stored in an `Address` entity related to an `Order` entity.

Everything works nicely if a user enters their billingAddress, but if a user removes a previously submitted billing address, I can find no way to remove the `billingAddress` entity. Ideally to remove the billing address I'd use the following JSON POST request.

```
{
    "email": "nick@example.com",
    "deliveryAddress": {
        "line1": "1 Box Lane"
    },
    "billingAddress": null
}
```

Is this at all possible with Symfony forms?

See below for a simplified explanation of the current setup.

**Entities**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var Address
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity = "Address", cascade = {"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "deliveryAddressId", referencedColumnName = "addressId")
     */
    private $deliveryAddress;

    /**
     * @var Address
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity = "Address", cascade = {"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval = true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "billingAddressId", referencedColumnName = "addressId", nullable = true)
     */
    private $billingAddress;

    public function setDeliveryAddress(Address $deliveryAddress = null)
    {
        $this->deliveryAddress = $deliveryAddress;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryAddress()
    {
        return $this->deliveryAddress;
    }

    public function setBillingAddress(Address $billingAddress = null)
    {
        $this->billingAddress = $billingAddress;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getBillingAddress()
    {
        return $this->billingAddress;
    }

    // ...
}
```

.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type = "string", length = 45, nullable = true)
     */
    private $line1;

    // ...
}
```

**Forms**

```
class CheckoutType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('deliveryAddress', AddressType::class, [
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('billingAddress', AddressType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Order::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

.

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('line1', TextType::class);
            // ...
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Address::class,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form events are what you need: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

For example if you want to remove the `billingAddress` field after the form submission you can do that:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('deliveryAddress', AddressType::class, [
            'required' => true
        ])
        ->add('billingAddress', AddressType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ]);

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if (empty($data['billingAddress'])) {
            $form->remove('billingAddress');
        }
    });
}
```

Read carefully the documentation to know which event will be the best for your scenario.

Comment: Interesting idea, have adapted this as simply removing the element did not update the entity. Will post an update later when I get a chance. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "by_reference" option for the "billingAddress" field to false in order to make sure that the setter is called.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#by-reference

Comment: If you supply billingAddress: null in the request payload it still isn't called though.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Renan and Raphael's answers as they led me to discovering the below solution which works for both a partial PATCH and full POST request.

```
class CheckoutType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var bool */
    private $removeBilling = false;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('deliveryAddress', AddressType::class, [
                'constraints' => [new Valid]
            ])
            ->add('billingAddress', AddressType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'constraints' => [new Valid]
            ])
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPreSubmit'])
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPostSubmit']);
    }

    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $this->removeBilling = array_key_exists('billingAddress', $data) && is_null($data['billingAddress']);
    }

    public function onPostSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->removeBilling) {
            $event->getData()->setBillingAddress(null);
        }
    }

}
```